# How to get last frame from video?

Tags: ios, swift, video

I want last frame of video and my code is shown below:

```
let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoURL, options: nil)
    let generate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    var err : NSError? = nil
    var lastFrameTime = Int64(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))
    let time : CMTime = CMTimeMake(lastFrameTime, 30)
    let imgRef : CGImageRef = generate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: &err)
    let img : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imgRef)!
```

But I am not getting last frame , I am getting first frame, provide me solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this , to get only last frame from video the code is following:

```
  let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoURL, options: nil)
    let generate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    var err : NSError? = nil
    var lastFrameTime = Int64(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)*60.0)
    let time : CMTime = CMTimeMake(lastFrameTime, 2)
    let imgRef : CGImageRef = generate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: &err)
    let img : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imgRef)!
```

This is how I get last image of video in img variable.

Comment: here why you are using hard code value 2 of preferredTimeScale?

Comment: I am still getting the first frame

Answer (score 3):

I used Pooja's code as a starting point but it doesn't get the last frame. it gets something close to the last frame. Here is my solution for getting the actual last frame. If frame accuracy is important, then you have to use:

```
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero
```

Be aware that it may take longer to generate this frame accurate last frame so you probably want to do it on a background thread.

Here is the code I am using:

```
let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset!)
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero

let composition = AVVideoComposition(propertiesOfAsset: asset!)
let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(asset!.duration.seconds, composition.frameDuration.timescale)

do {
    let imageRef = try imageGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can get last frame of video in Objective-C as mentioned below:-

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
    generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

    NSError *error;

    int64_t lastFrameTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)*60.0;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(lastFrameTime, 2);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
```

Comment: Please post relevant code the OP has asked the question about Swift I don't see how objective c code can help.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer produce the first frame.

This code works (objective-c)

```
AVAsset* asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
generate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
generate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;

NSError *error;
CMTime time = asset.duration;
CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
```

The main lines here are :

```
generate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
generate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
```

and

```
CMTime time = asset.duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the last frame from the video after a lot of attempts.

```swift
let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

// Make sure you set the next two properties. 
// It didn't work for me without this two parameters!
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .positiveInfinity

let lastFrameTime = Int64(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration) * 60)
time = CMTime(value: lastFrameTime, timescale: 2)

guard let imageRef = try? imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) else { 
    return
}

let thumbnailImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
```