# Get last frame from video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm trying to get last frame from video. Last frame, not last second (because I have very fast videos, one second can have different scenes).

I've written such code for testing:

```
private func getLastFrame(from item: AVPlayerItem) -> UIImage? {
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: item.asset)

    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero

    let composition = AVVideoComposition(propertiesOf: item.asset)
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(item.asset.duration.seconds, composition.frameDuration.timescale)

    do {
        let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

But I receive always such error when try to execute it:

> Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11832 "Cannot Open"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170240180 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12431 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media cannot be used.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}

If I remove `requestedTimeTolerance` (so it will be on default infinite value) everything is okay, but I always receive brighter imaged than I have in video (maybe it is because not latest frame was captured? Or CGImage → UIImage transform has some troubles?)

Questions:

1. Why I receive error when zero tolerance is specified? How to get exactly last frame?
2. Why captured images may be overbrighted that in video? For example if I write such code:

   ```
   self.videoLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
   self.backgroundImageView.image = getLastFrame(from: playerItem)
   ```

I see "brightness jump" (video was darker, image is brighter).

#### Update 1

I found related issue: [AVAssetImageGenerator fails at copying image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935247/avassetimagegenerator-fails-at-copying-image), but that question is not solved.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42967138/620665

Comment: @Vasily I am seeing the same with the brighter image. It is very strange indeed. Same for first frame of the video as well.

Comment: Additionally, I cannot get the very last frame either. It always takes perhaps a few milliseconds BEFORE the last frame.

Comment: @Vasily did you found the solution?